# the_date appearing on front page, not on posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I've put the_date on the entry-header on my posts on the front page (example http://atactilelife.com.au) through editing content.php however when you click on a link to display it as a single post the date disappears (example http://atactilelife.com.au/meat-free-wednesday-asparagus-pumpkin-tart)

Which .php file do I edit to put it into an individual post?

And the bigger question - when I inspect an element through a browser like firefox or chrome, is there a way I can tell which .php file I should be editing?

Thanks!

Comment: _single.php_? You provide not enough informations. I've checked page you post here as example, so I detect that you are using _wordpress_ with _twentytwelve_ template. Am I right? Location of single post is based on theme, so if you are using different theme or your own custom theme, it will be really hard to help you.

Comment: No, you cannot tell which file you should be editing unless you manually edit these files ahead of time and place flags in them to do things like `<!-- BEGIN myfile.php--> // <!--END myfile.php-->`. Furthermore, content.php is only loaded when the `get_template_part('content.php');` is called, or some variation of this. So further files should be edited. Did you try other files?

Comment: I have edited single.php, however I cant get the date to appear in the same location as the one on the front page. I can get it to appear on top of it, because as Ohgodwhy says content.php is loaded as a whole, but not letting the date appear as per my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I didn't try this, but on that file ( content.php ) try to add this between line 25 and 26

**This is a short preview from line 24 to 26**

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
// post the code below here !! <-------------------------------------
<?php else : ?>
```

**Date code:**

```
<div class="single-post-date">
    <span><?php the_time('d') ?></span>
    <span><?php the_time('M') ?></span>
</div>
```

I wrapped the date inside the class `.single-post-date` so you can costumize it as you want

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured out the problem! I didnt add the code for entrydate in the else part of an if-then-else structure.

The solution was to simply move the line of code which outputs the date to just after the endif statement so it gets output regardless of whether it's in a single post page or an index page.